# get xml value based on attribute with jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

I want to get all the values of the items where the name="id" and append these values to the div to be used for future purposes.

I have the following XML:

[Pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/K5kH8uEC)

and this is my jQuery:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "http://test.be/",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: soapMessage2,
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"UTF-8\"",
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('item[name="id"]').each(function() {
            var libr = $(this).text();
            $('#lib').append('<a href="#">' + libr + '</a>');
        });
    }
});
```

I can't seem to find why nothing gets added to the div. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are you sure that the AJAX request that retrieves the XML is working correctly, and that it's retuning exactly what you expect?

Comment: is there any error in your console

Comment: The AJAX requests works correctly, and I don't get any errors in my console. The weird thing is if I retrieve a single value by using: var id = xml.getElementsByTagName("value")[4].childNodes[0].nodeValue; the ID is returned as it should, the reason I can't use this is that there are multiple ID's that need to be returned but for some reason it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by using the following code:

```
   $(xml).find('key').each(function() {
   if($(this).text().toLowerCase() === "id"){
        // var libr = $(this).closest("item").find("value").text();
        var libr = $(this).next().text(); //alternate method for acessing                    
        $('#lib').append('<p><a href="#">' + libr + '</a></p>'); 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

i've tried your code, and it's work perfectly !

The only thing I see: is you code in the scope of $(document).ready()?

***Work***

```
<html>
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {
          var xml=<your xml>


                $(xml).find('item[name="id"]').each(function() {
                var libr = $(this).text();
                $('#lib').append('<a href="#">'+libr+'</a>');
                });
            });
        </script>

      </head>
      <body>
        <div>should see 16: <span id='lib'></span></div>

      </body>
    </html>
```

> should see 16: 16

***Doesn't Work***

```
<html>
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

          var xml=<your xml>


                $(xml).find('item[name="id"]').each(function() {
                var libr = $(this).text();
                $('#lib').append('<a href="#">'+libr+'</a>');
                });

        </script>

      </head>
      <body>
         <div>should see 16: <span id='lib'></span></div>

      </body>
    </html>
```

> should see 16:

Comment: Hi, I've tried this but it doesn't work, My jquery file exists of multiple soap calls: 
login -> auth token is retrieved to validate the user and in this method, when it's successful, the libraryretrieve method is called.
show libraries -> uses auth token as parameter to show all the libraries for that user, I don't get why the xml.find doesn't work, when I give in just 'item' as parameter it gives all the values of all the items, but I can't to seem to give a attribute in the search

Comment: Can you log the result of find?

            console.log(libr);

Comment: The console doesn't say anything after the ajax function has been done.

Answer (score 0):

The code works for me.
I didn't get any errors back from the console.

It's more about this thing here var id = xml.getElementsByTagName("value")[4].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

FYI you need to train your meKanix,

┏(-*-)┛┗(-*- )┓┗(-*-)┛┏(-*-) ┏(-*-)┓┏(-*-)┛┗(-*- )┓┗(-*-)┛┏(-*-)┓ ┏(-*-)┛┗(-*- )┓┗(-*-)┛┏(-*-)┓┏(-*-)┛┗(-*- )┓┗(-*-)┛┏(-*-)┓┏(-*-)┛┗(-*- )┓┗(-*-)┛┏(-_-)┓

Comment: You ought to confine your answer to just answering